# Can anyone identify this outdoor faucet manufacturer from the mid 70s?

Tags: plumbing

I have two of these outside of my house and would like to replace the stem?  Any idea who the manufacturer is?[image]

Comment: So what brand was it? And what's the name of the specialty supply shop? I'm in the exact same boat. Maybe the can help me mail order. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Way late but that's a Rockwell / Rockwell-Sterling sillcock.
Came here having the same issue. No luck finding parts online, trying to hit some stores on the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that the brass body of the hose bib is almost always sound and that to try to remove it can lead to much more work than you are prepared for.  I think most plumbing or hardware stores will stock all the replacement parts you will need, including a kit to "dress" or smooth out the sealing surface where the washer closes against.  Also, seriously, look for an old guy like me in your neighborhood who has all the parts you'd need, to rebuild several spigots, and would be glad to share.

Comment: Flightrn: being male I hate crawling under houses.  Spiders, centipedes and snakes don't care about gender when they bite.

Comment: I appreciate all your comments I was able to locate a specialty plumbing supply store yesterday. They had the parts to fix both faucets and they are functional now.

Answer (score 0):

Those are such a common type of faucet that you may want to just consider replacing the whole thing. They should just screw onto a pipe that extends out beyond the brick work by about a 2 to 3cm.

Only issue you may have to deal with is that it would be a good idea to grasp the pipe on the inside of the wall so that it does not turn when removing the faucet. A buddy or partner on the other side with a pipe wrench should do the trick.

Comment: Is the standard arrangement that the inner threaded connection is accessible (say through an access port) for holding with a pipe wrench? It would seem to me that if the inner connections were not normally accessible, best practice would be to have wrenching flats or at least  a clear spot on the pipe to hold it on the outside (with some thin profile pipe wrench.  Would a first rate plumber be able to detect if the inner joint would come loose when he unscrewed the spigot, in which case he would remove the inner pipe, re-apply pipe dope and redo that threaded joint too?

Comment: What material is the water piping in this house? If it is sweated copper, then there will be a male adapter to pipe threads sweated on the end of the copper. If one chips away the mortar, a thin wrench (like a bicycle type) could hold onto the wrenching flats. Surely there is a standard way to wrench on the spigot without damaging the upstream piping.

Comment: Does this house have a way to cut off the outside faucets without cutting off all the water to the house? My 47-year-old, inexpensive tract house has valving to cut-off the two outside faucets. Unfortunately all of this valving has long since corroded and is inoperable. The only way I  have to cut off the water to an outside faucet is to turn off all the water to the house at the city valve at the meter. I know of only one person in my neighborhood who has had the original valving replaced. The original valve are brass gate valves. Mine are all frozen either open or closed.

Comment: If you would take this picture to a local plumbing supply, they might be able to tell you the mfgr of the faucet and could get a new stem. Why do you need a new stem? Maybe you only need the sealing washer and valve seat (if replaceable).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure what I need. There appears to be a cracked white plastic washer on both. Neither of them will shut off by turning the valve. I can turn the water off the the whole house and stop them from leaking.  Being female I am afraid to go under the house to see about connections.